# Copy all cells with data from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with some sheets. I need to copy all cells with data from it and copy it to another excel document in sheet with name "All data". And then I need to check if value in column H is null or "0" I need to remove all row where this value is.  How can I do this?

Here is my code that get data from file but I am not sure that I tahe only data (and without empty cells)

```
 Windows("Book1").Activate
 Sheets(1).Cells.Select
 Selection.Copy
```

Comment: Hi OP, I suggest you use the "Record Macro" function under "Developer" Tab and record the actions you mentioned and observe the codes

Comment: I support Larry's comment, as it will allow you to see the specific functions and Excel local variables clearly. Then you might alter any specific references (string formatted sheet names etc) with more general or variable ones and iterate over them...

Comment: Yes, I am new in vba. I take this code in my handler.

Comment: Using the Record Macro button will allow you to learn the language quickly

Comment: You can post the code you recorded, then we can make it more generic

Comment: I have tried but when I select range of cell for insert there was an error. I have found information that it is much better to avoid select method so I have resolve this issue not with code from macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Dim n as integer
Dim n1 as integer

n = 0
n1 = 0

While Sheet("Book1").Range("A1").Offset(n, 0) <> ""
    If Sheet("Book1").Range("H1").Offset(n, 0) <> null then     
       If Sheet("Book1").Range("H1").Offset(n, 0) <> 0 then
          Sheet("Book1").Range("A1:Z1").Offset(n, 0).Copy
          Sheet("All Data").Range("A1:Z1").Offset(n1, 0).Paste
          n1 = n1 + 1
       End If
    End If
    n = n + 1
Wend
```

Answer (score 0):

This will copy the data to Sheet2, change this to your other sheet/  area. It will then filter the data, delete the visible rows (data based on criteria) and then remove the filter:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Sheet2.Range("A1")

With Sheet2
    .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=0, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="Null"
    .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Resize(.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count - 1) _
                                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```