# Sort table by column value (from max to min)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with some values:

[image]

I need to sort this table with vba by the Value column from max to min value. How can I do this?

Comment: as per the comment by @Larry in your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837754/copy-all-cells-with-data-from-one-sheet-to-another) it is advised to use the Record macro button under the Developer tab in Excel. Works brilliantly for explorating VBA with Excel. If the Developer tab is not available then you can find it by going (Office 2007 and 2010) to the Office button > Excel Options > Show Developer tab in the Ribbon.

Comment: but sometimes it is not work

Comment: for this it will work, i know for sure. It only doesnt work for certain embedded objects, but overall all your actions (also committing changes via interaction with the ribbon) get recorded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this is what you need

```
Columns("A:E").Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("E2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

Comment: and in result make table will change with sorted one?

Comment: This will Reorder your table with 100 at the top and 10 at the bottom.